# How can i bypass/protect myself from ransomware like ctb-locker?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, privacy-protection

Recently while using my system for testing  I got my machine infected with a malware,

My system gets displayed with the following screen :

[image]

While browsing internet with screenshot i found that its [ctb-locker](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkc.mcafee.com%2Fresources%2Fsites%2FMCAFEE%2Fcontent%2Flive%2FPRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION%2F25000%2FPD25696%2Fen_US%2FMcAfee_Labs_Threat_Advisory-CTB-Locker.pdf&ei=4XeaVYLEO8iUuQTajoSIAw&usg=AFQjCNFZ-fu9Tw-t1sCMtX4odYxfjRPDVw&bvm=bv.96952980,d.c2E) and its demanding money inorder to decrypt my files

The possible solutions which i could explore where :

system restore and format a system

But as per recent post the ctb locker encrypts shadow copies too..

is it there any way to bypass and decrypt all data?

P.S Got infected at my ubuntu machine any solutions for ubuntu?

Comment: No; There is no way to bypass and decrypt your files without the key required to do so.  Which is the reason the virus is so effective at its job.  There are variation of a similar file called "Cryptolocker" which had a flaw, but since that original variation, those flaws have been fixed.   Why is this tagged as linux when the malware in question is a Windows only infection?

Comment: @Ramhound got infected under my ubuntu machine so tagged linux

Comment: @Ramhound dear friend,kindly let me know how to prove its infected with linux,so that i could provide evidence for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=fix+ransomware+ctb) doesn't give great news unfortunately:

> The bad part about this whole story is you cannot be sure you’ll get your files back intact, unless of course you pay the ransom. There is no tool that can handle the crypto as strong as that for the time being.

*(per http://malwareprotectioncenter.com/2015/02/06/ctb-locker/ as an example, other places say similar things)*

Recovery amounts to:

- backups
- data recovery tools to find the deleted files on disk
- shadow volume backups (Shadow Explorer) / Windows 'previous versions of this file' / etc (*as you note, later versions of **ctb** try to obviate this method*)
- previously, `pandaunransom.exe` (and similar may have worked), but are unlikely to against newer variants

Hopefully you have backups; if not it is worth trying the shadow volumes (etc) as they may not have been affected, depending on version of ctb-locker.

**Edit**: I see DavidPostill has linked to a previous question which pretty much says the same thing ([Got ransomware and Shadow explorer dont work](https://superuser.com/questions/907189/got-ransomware-and-shadow-explorer-dont-work))

Comment: but how about for my linux machine?i cant find shadow copies at my linux?what would be the possible solution for linux machine

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 AFAICT ctb-ransom only affects Windows currently: "The CTB-Locker ransomware currently affects Microsoft Windows operating systems only; if further variants affecting Linux and/or Mac OS X are discovered then further bulletins will be released." per http://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/oxcert/2015/02/06/ctb-locker-ransomware-campaign/ What has happened to the Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

Symantec, F-Secure, Trend Micro all agree it's Windows-only, though the newest I could find is from Feb 2015.

Wondering if maybe you have Wine(or similar/derivative) running and infected.

Not sure what would happen if you just purge Wine...

(Or a VM?)